# Recursividade em Python

Tags: python, recursão

Seguinte galera, tenho uma matriz que é um tabuleiro de batalha naval representada pela lista:

```
tab = [['.', '.', '#', '#', '#'], 
       ['.', '.', '.', '.', '.'], 
       ['#', '#', '#', '#', '#'], 
       ['.', '.', '.', '.', '.'], 
       ['#', '.', '#', '#', '.']]
```

onde essa recursividade checa as '#' que são navio, e '#' ao lado de '#' são navio grande. 
Então a função percorre essa lista salva as posições dos navios grandes e pequenos nas outras listas.

**Dúvida**:
eu gostaria de saber o seguinte, quando essa função que está abaixo é executada
ela percorre uma matriz, infelizmente tem que usar a matriz mesmo, mas quando ela acha 
o x ela retorna a função recursiva e as informações anteriormente é 'empilhada' no 
compilador do python, só que após ela fazer essa recursão ela continua rodando o 
empilhamento, ou seja, ela faz o laço n^2 após terminar o laço inteiro, ela desempilha 
a função recursiva e volta ao laço n^2 que foi o que estava acontecendo anteriormente 
antes dela chama a função recursiva, ai eu gostaria de saber se tem como após ela checar
com a função recursiva ela parar e não fazer mais com n^2, se não ficou muito claro 
a pergunta deixa um comentário que tento explicar novamente com outras palavras.

código:

```
def checar(c,l):
global navio
global  encontrados
global checado
if not checado:
    try:
        if tab[c][l] == '#':
            y = c
            x = l
            if y>=0 and x>=0:
                encontrados.append((y+1, x+1))
                checado.append((y, x))
    except IndexError:
        pass
try:
    if tab[c-1][l] == '#':
        y = c-1
        x = l
        if y>=0 and x>=0:
            tab[y][x] = 'x'
            encontrados.append((y+1,x+1))
            checado.append((y, x))
except IndexError:
    pass
try:
    if tab[c][l-1] == '#':
        y = c
        x = l-1
        if y>=0 and x>=0:
            tab[y][x] = 'x'
            encontrados.append((y+1,x+1))
            checado.append((y, x))
except IndexError:
    pass

try:
    if tab[c][l+1] == '#':
        y = c
        x = l+1
        if y>=0 and x>=0:
            tab[y][x] = 'x'
            encontrados.append((y+1,x+1))
            checado.append((y, x))
except IndexError:
    pass
try:
    if tab[c+1][l] == '#':
        y = c+1
        x = l
        if y>=0 and x>=0:
            tab[y][x] = 'x'
            encontrados.append((y+1,x+1))
            checado.append((y, x))
except IndexError:
    pass
tab[c][l] = '.'
for c in range(len(tab)):
   for l in range(len(tab)):
       if tab[c][l] == 'x':
           checar(c,l)
           tab[c][l] = '.'
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Nessa imagem de cima é possível visualizar minha duvida, eu gostaria de saber se é possível após termino da recursividade 1, ele não desempilhasse, ou seja, não fosse para a 2 e depois 3 mas sim ele saia da def e vá para a global direto. Ou se tem alguma forma melhor de fazer isso, sou iniciante ainda em programação.

Comment: Provavelmente não precisa ser recursivo, mas só uma dúvida: qual deveria ser o resultado final? O que deveriam ter `checado`, `encontrado` e `navio`?

Comment: Os navios, o resultado final de encontrados é os navios, seja ele navio pequeno ou grande, ai depois de encontrado ele manda para a lista navio que é essa [[(1, 3),(1, 4), (1, 5)],  [(3, 1), (3, 2), (3, 3), (3, 4), (3, 5)],  [(5, 1)], [(5, 3), (5, 4)]] cada lista dessa é uma parte de encontrado que essas são as localizações dos navios, para quando o usuário informa a entrada da bomba, eu só percorrer a lista com a informação da bomba e remover, no final a quantidade que fica é os navios que sobraram, pois para derrubar um navio, tem que acertar todas as partes dele.

Comment: já o resultado de checado, é o mesmo só que a lista de 0 a n, já de encontrado vai de 1 a n porque o usuário coloca a localização da bomba informando linha e coluna com números maiores que 0.

Comment: e infelizmente já estou observando problemas na hora de checar, está tudo certo o salvamento das localizações, mas esse checar que vai me dar problema

Comment: Qual é a saída esperada ? O navios sempre estariam representados na horizontal ? As linhas impares da sua matriz sempre serão formadas por `.` (pontos) ? Se um navio pequeno é representado por uma `#` (*hashtag*) e um navio grande por duas *hashtags*, o que seriam três *hashtags* ?

Comment: navio grande também kkkk, é uma questão da obi que está me tirando do serio, 4 dias que estou trabalhando nela e todas as ideias que eu tenho não da certo essa é a última ideia e acabou de dar errado, está extremamente pesado essa recursão, tenho que entregar isso sexta, kkkk caso se interesse na questão está ai o link: https://olimpiada.ic.unicamp.br/pratique/p2/2010/f1/batalha/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nao entendi muito bem sua pergunta, mas vamos la. vc tem um laço que chama uma funcional recursiva e quer que depois q ele execute essa função uma vez ela nao volte a ser executada? Se for isso tem varias maneiras, colocar uma flag que caso ele seja true vc executa e se ja tiver executado vc coloca ele para falso, a ultra opçao e colocar um break logo apos as linhas que quer executar apenas uma vez assim forçando a saida do laço.

No caso do break:

```py
    for c in range(len(tab)):
       for l in range(len(tab)):
           if tab[c][l] == 'x':
               checar(c,l)
               tab[c][l] = '.'
               break
```

No caso da Flag:

```py
    flag = True
    for c in range(len(tab)):
       for l in range(len(tab)):
           if flag:
               if tab[c][l] == 'x':
                   checar(c,l)
                   tab[c][l] = '.'
                   flag = False
```

No caso da flag e mais interessante caso ainda queira percorrer o vetor mas sem executar esse bloco em especifico, caso contrario o melhor seria o break que vai forçar a saida do laço.

se tiver erro de sintaxe e pq faz um tempo q nao mexo com phyton.